# Confusion around Boolean Logic

Tags: python, pandas, database

I often keep running into this problem, where I want to implement some Boolean condition and I keep running into the problem that is presented below.

For instance, say I have a Data Frame with a R2 column and I want to only print out R2 values greater than or equal to R >= 0.70. This is the code I wrote:

```
for rval in df1.R2:
    if rval >= 0.70:
        df5 = pd.merge(df4.Variables, df1, how = "inner")
print(df5)
```

Instead of only printing out values >= 0.70, all the rows from df1 are getting printed out. I understand that this is because all the condition I've stated are being met. However, I would like to only print out values, where the R2 is greater than or equal to 0.70. This is but an example. Essentially, I would like to apply this sort of logic to various situations. I just don't know how to go about it smartly.

I would really appreciate any help with regards to this. Ideally, I would prefer a solution that won't make use of any pre-existing Pandas function but rather one that I can use for any scenario moving forward.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Nothing in `pd.merge(df4.Variables, df1, how = "inner")` refers to the current row of the loop. It's merging the entire dataframe.

Comment: To get the subset that matches the condition, use `df1[df1['R2'] >= 0.70]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `pd.merge()` call you merge the entire `df1`, not just the current row that matched the condition. Also, you're replacing `df5` each time, so it won't accumulate all the matching rows.

You shouldn't generally loop over dataframe rows. use panda's built-in filtering.

```
df5 = pd.merge(df4.Variables, df1[df1.R2 >= 0.70], how="inner")
```